# Disabled HTTP methods on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I have a Ruby on Rails application that is being hosted on Heroku.

For a security review to allow our application, we've been told to disable a number of HTTP methods.

> "The application web server must be configured to disable the TRACE
>   and other HTTP methods if not being used."

Is this possible with Heroku? If not, is there a way to disable these methods on the application level?

Comment: **Update:** Heroku has gotten back to me saying it's not possible on there end. So it's now a question about application level rejection.

Comment: Was this ok with Intuit or did you have move servers?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

On the application level, you could add this in your application_controller.rb file

```
  before_filter :reject_methods

  def reject_methods
    if ['TRACE','PATCH'].include?(request.method)
      #raise ActionController::RoutingError.new('Not Found')
      raise ActionController::MethodNotAllowed.new('Method not allowed')  #405
      # or whatever you want to do (redirect, error message, ...)
    end
  end
```

Or you could try with https://github.com/jtrupiano/rack-rewrite (check the arbitrary rewriting) with something like this (not tested) :

```
rewrite %r{(.*)}, lambda { |match, rack_env|
  rack_env["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "TRACE" ? "405.html" : match[1]
}
```

Or you could use you own middleware by putting this in a file ./lib:

```
module Rack

class RejectMethods
  def initialize(app)
    @app = app
  end

  def call(env)
    status, headers, body = @app.call(env)

    if env["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "TRACE" || env["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "PATCH"
      body.close if body.respond_to? :close
      [status, headers, []]
    else
      [status, headers, body]
    end
  end
end

end
```

and call it in application.rb

```
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)

config.middleware.use "RejectMethods"
```